# Google Sheets: Get Daily Yield From Compounded Annual Percentage Yield (APY)

Tags: google-sheets, finance

I'm looking for a function that is almost the opposite of FV().

In cryptocurrency tokens, returns are sometimes quoted as a compounded Annual Percentage Yield (APY).  These tokens can make payments in periods which are daily, or even each hour, or each 8 hours, etc.

So I'd like to work out the yield per period, from the compounded APY.

I've looked through the financial functions at [Google Sheets > Financial](https://support.google.com/docs/topic/3105398?hl=en&ref_topic=3046366)  but most of these are way over my head.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

[Edit]  I've tried using FV(), by using 365 periods per year, and (say) $100 for current value, seeing what the outcome is to get an APY - but I have to keep modifying that daily rate until I get close to the APY that's quoted. In other words, I'm trying to do it *backwards*.  Must be a function that can do this though?

Comment: C'mon you've got an `SO` rating of 1,539... [How can you post a question like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? What have you tried? What would a proper formula return for a couple scenarios? What the heck does "the opposite of FV()" mean?? I'd be thrilled to look at this (crypto interests me) but this question needs improvement.

Comment: Not sure how to improve the question.  If an APY is, say, 550%, what is the yield per period (eg a day). I'm making a lot on reflection tokens, but these are frequently advertised with an APY.  So I'd like to figure out the daily yield, as that is what the token is compounding by, which the APY reflects.

Comment: Hi there @maxhugen! I don't fully understand the monetary side of your question. Could you please show an example showing your actual and desired data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mulling over this for some time, a moment of clarity yielded the surprisingly simple answer.

```
Given:
  p (periods) = 365*3    (ie, each 8 hours, for a year)
              = 1095
  r (rate)    = 1.8%
Then:
  APY = (1 + r) ^ p 
      = (1 + 1.8%) ^ 1095 
      = 30,466,103,336.2661%
```

So to get the Rate from the APY it becomes:

```
  r = APY ^ 1/p - 1 
    = 30,466,103,336.2661% ^ 1/1095 - 1
    = 1.8%
```